# Turing-unrecognizable language - what TM does?

Tags: computability, turing-machines

I have a problem giving "intuitive" explanation to turing-unrecognizable languages.

We can prove that, say, ${\overline{A_{TM}}}$ is not turing-recognizable, because that would make ${{A_{TM}}}$ decidable, but what would the $TM$ do if it doesn't accept, reject of loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might be a little confused by a definition somewhere.  A TM $M$ is a recognizer for a language $L$ if it

- Accepts every string in $L$
- Either rejects or loops on every string not in $L$

Now let's think about the language ${\overline{A_{TM}}}$.  An input $\langle N,x\rangle$ is in ${\overline{A_{TM}}}$ if either:

- $N$ rejects on $x$.
- $N$ loops on $x$

So any recognizer will need to figure out (in finite time) that $N$ is going to loop on some input, which is just the halting problem.

Comment: Thanks for connecting it to the halting problem. From there I stumbled on this resource and it sort of brought things to order http://www.cgl.uwaterloo.ca/~csk/halt/.